# How to select a new texture in the displacement modifier

Tags: displacement

I'm frustrated. I am trying to apply a displacement modifier to a mesh but I am stuck because I cannot figure out how to select a different texture in modifier. I want to use a cloud texture to make subtle deformations of the mesh. How do I select a new, different texture? The tutorials I've watched all have a dialogue box (that I am not seeing) where you can select image or film and find the texture through that, but again, I am not seeing that at all. What's going wrong?[image]

Comment: If you watch those tutorials closely you will find that the texture type is selected from the texture properties window, by either going to the appropriate tab, or clicking the texture settings button in the far right of the texture name

Answer (score 1):

You must go to another tab first to set up the texture.

Go down to the **texture properties** tab, select new.  Click on image or Movie and then add "Clouds" from the drop down list.

[image]

[image]

Select the object, and go back to the modifier tab. The new texture will be available in the drop down list.

[image]